# Import (migrate) tests from TestLink to Zephyr

Tags: testlink

What is the best way to import tests (test cases, suites) from TestLink to Zephyr?

Comment: Hi @Ann did you find a way to do this? I'm currently looking at moving to Zephyr but I want to move our Testlink data across.

Answer (score 1):

I found this which seems to answer your question.

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/184845/importing-test-cases-to-zephyr-add-on-from-test-link

You need an importer plugin found here

http://community.yourzephyr.com/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=1048

Answer (score 0):

You can download the [Zephyr Testcase Importer](https://bitbucket.org/zfjdeveloper/zfj-importer/downloads) to import Excel or XML files into Zephyr. As far as I know, this importer utility performs a 'flat' import of all testcases, so you will lose all information regarding test plans, test suites and the test execution history.